# Inquisitors and Kandra

Tags: cosmere, mistborn, the-final-empire

In *Mistborn: The Final Empire*, Kelsier's crew are holding their first major planning session. Breeze wonders why Kelsier can't send the fake Lord Renoux to the parties:

> "Well, that should be easy," Breeze said. "We just bring up your impostor and send him into the parties."

Kelsier replies:

> Oh, he looks just like Lord Renoux. *Exactly* like Lord Renoux, actually. We just can't let him get near an Inquisitor.

If that's the case, why did the Inquisitor stick an axe into the kandra impersonating Lord Renoux during his battle with Kelsier? Shouldn't the Inquistor have observed that his target was a kandra? Afterwards, Dockson comments that the axe to the back might not have been fatal for the kandra.

Comment: During the battle, the Inquisitor was probably too busy to be paying close attention to whether a nearby person was actually a kandra in disguise.

Comment: I don't understand the question, it appears Kandra are kill on sight so why wouldn't the inquisitor attempt to kill him?

Comment: @A.K, why would be kandra be kill on sight for Inquisitors? Since it's noted that Inquisitors can detect Kandra, wouldn't it make sense for the Inquisitor to select a more fatal method of dealing with one?

Answer (score 5):

Heat of battle.

It's not made clear exactly how any particular Inquisitor could detect a kandra, but since it's known that they can potentially pierce copperclouds, it stands to reason that they could sense the metal spikes inside a kandra's body.  It may require a bit of concentration, given that at normal power levels internal metals do not show up, or perhaps simply through their common link of Hemalurgic spikes they would be able to sense a kindred creature.

Since an Inquisitor's visual senses are actually entirely through the spikes, in some sort of super metal sense, that may even make it more obvious.

It's just not likely to be something an inquisitor cares to address when in mortal combat with a full Mistborn, distraction equalling death and all.  Not that that helped in the end.